# cmd.Output in concurrent, get empty byte slide randomly

Tags: go, concurrency

I am using Cmd.Output to get the results from a series of commands concurrently. It can worked well in serial, but after I turned to code into parallel, some output byte slides return empty (should be contents inside), and some are well. Can I ask anyone know the reason? Thank you! I tried to make a reseach but no answer.

```
for _, nodeArn := range nodeArnList {
           wgManifestIO.Add(1)
           go generateCmd(stage, nodeArn)
       }
```

```
func generateCmd(stage string, arn string) {
    var cmdSlice []string = make([]string, 0)   
    outfile, err := os.Create(meshName + ".json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("os.Create: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("recover: %v\n", err)
        }
        outfile.Close()
        wgManifestIO.Done()
    }()
    cmdSlice = append(cmdSlice, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    cmd := exec.Command(arg0, cmdSlice...)
    ioLock.Lock() // if wrapped the output() statement in lock, it worked again, but then it is still serial. 
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    ioLock.Unlock()
    if len(out) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("empty exception") // get some empty slides, and some successful slides, in random
    }
    _, err = outfile.Write(out)
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to show anything parallel. How did you make your code parallel?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is a parallel function. Let me modify the codes to be more clear

Comment: What is the command you're running? It could be that the command program itself doesn't support parallel execution

Comment: I think it is a command support parallel. Sorry since it is internal comapny command, so I am not allowwed to show here.

Comment: What is the error returned from `cmd.Output()` when an empty slice is returned?   Is it possible that the application breached the fd limit because `len(nodeArnList)` is large?